# Broadcast task to all workers: redis+celery

Tags: python, redis, celery, broadcast

tasks.py

```
    from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks',
             broker='redis://localhost',
             backend='redis://localhost',
             include=['tasks'])

app.conf.broker_url = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
# Optional configuration, see the application user guide.
app.conf.update(
    result_expires=3600,
)
@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

main.py

```
from tasks import add


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        from celery import Celery
        app = Celery('tasks', backend='redis://localhost', broker='redis:localhost//')
        result = add.delay(4, 4)
        result.ready()
        value = result.get(timeout=10)
        print(value)
```

I'd like to broadcast task to all workers with redis (broker and backend) and celery, but I didn't achieve, can you help me please ?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your comment, could you be more specific please

Comment: You have already a `app` in `tasks.py` and you create a new one in `__main__`.

Comment: yes it's true, I don't need the line in main.py:
app = Celery('tasks', backend='redis://localhost', broker='redis:localhost//')

Comment: Do you know, how can I broadcast task to all workers?

Comment: Have you tried `tasks.app`, as this `app` behaving different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18644511/broadcast-messages-in-celery

Comment: no, how can I use tasks.app?

Answer (score 0):

For instance:

```
import tasks
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tasks.app.do_something.apply_async(['222'], queue='broadcast_tasks')
```